# How to save camera instance?

Tags: android, android-camera

How to save the state of the camera so when i close the screen and turn it on again the camera gets back to its previous state.Should i bundle it?

```js
public void getCamera() {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();

            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(e.getMessage(), "Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error:Application will close! ");
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you don't want to do this-  you want to release the camera in onPause and recapture it in onResume so other apps can use it as well.